# How to get Access token cookies of on-premise Sharepoint using REST API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-on-prem

I want to access sharepoint on-premise list.

But i dont know how to get Access token of it. I am trying to make application in android.

any help will highly appreciated.

Comment: have you ever found the solution?